# Jackson Serializer called on wrong types

Tags: json, list, serialization, jackson, objectmapper

I'm working with Jackson and I've written the following custom serializer:

```
public class FooSerializer extends StdSerializer<List<Foo>> {

  public FooSerializer() {
    this(null);
  }

  public FooSerializer(Class<List<Foo>> t) {
    super(t);
  }

  public void serialize(List<Foo> foos, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
    gen.writeStartArray(foos.size());
    for(Foo foo : foos){
        gen.writeString(foo.getName());
    }
    gen.writeEndArray();
  }
}
```

I have registered it in the `ObjectMapper` as follows:

```
SimpleModule fooModule = new SimpleModule("Foo Module");
fooModule.addSerializer(new FooSerializer((Class<List<Foo>>)(Object)List.class));
objectMapper.registerModule(fooModule);
```

I'm expecting it to take an object holding a `List` of `Foo`s and return it like

```
{
  ...
  "foos":["name1", "name2"]
  ...
}
```

This works fine, however, when I'm passing a `List` of `SomeObjectHoldingFoos`, each holding a `List` of `Foo`, the ObjectMapper tries to apply the `FooSerializer` to this `List` already, resulting in the `Foo cannot be cast to SomeObjectHoldingFoos` Exception.

I'm suspecting that the `handledType` of the `FooSerializer` somehow was set as `List` instead of `List<Foo>` but I don't know how to fix that, since there seems to be no class for a paramerized type.

What can I do?

Comment: Just seeing through the code i was wondering whether List.class can be replaced with List<Foo>.class in the addSerializer part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JavaType` instead of `Class`.

```
class FooSerializer extends StdSerializer<List<Foo>> {

    FooSerializer(JavaType javaType) {
        super(javaType);
    }

    ....
}
```

And register it like below:

```
SimpleModule fooModule = new SimpleModule("Foo Module");
CollectionLikeType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionLikeType(ArrayList.class, Foo.class);
fooModule.addSerializer(new FooSerializer(type));
```

Comment: I've found another solution using the `StdConverter` but this works too, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've realized that I just needed a `Converter` and not a `Serializer`, I've implemented the following:

```
public class FooConverter extends StdConverter<Foo, String> {

  @Override
  public String convert(Foo value) {
    return value.getName();
  }

  public static SimpleModule getSimpleModule(){
    SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
    simpleModule.addSerializer(Foo.class, new StdDelegatingSerializer(new FooConverter()));
    return simpleModule;
  }
}
```

and I registered it as follows:

```
SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
simpleModule.addSerializer(TAGWrapper.class, new StdDelegatingSerializer(new TagWrapperConverter()));
objectMapper.registerModule()
```